# If an if block returns in JavaScript, is there a need for else?

Tags: javascript, performance, if-statement

I'm currently trying to squeeze every last millisecond from a JavaScript program that is fired on an event listener at a rate of 10x per second. I'm trying to remove all cruft. When an `if` block's sole purpose is to `return` something if true, is there any advantage to following with `else if` or `else`, or am I right in thinking that I forgo `else`.

eg.

```
// with else
function withElse () {
    if (foo) {
        return foo;
    } else if (bar) {
        return bar;
    } else {
        return baz;
    }
}

// without else
function withoutElse () {
    if (foo) return foo;
    if (bar) return bar;
    return baz;
}
```

Comment: I believe you are correct. However, this is very easy to test and be sure once and for all.

Comment: Personally I think that `else` after a block with a `return` is kind-of an anti-pattern. Then again some people think that `return` in the middle of a function is a bad thing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is better? if..else or multiple simple if](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139496/what-is-better-if-else-or-multiple-simple-if)

Comment: I much prefer the latter for readability.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139496/what-is-better-if-else-or-multiple-simple-if, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429893/if-else-vs-if-for-performance-and-readability, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820839/using-return-instead-of-else-in-javascript

Comment: The `else` is going to cost a microsecond or two at compile time, other than that, no performance impact whatsoever. I'm sure there are more interesting things to optimize in your program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't. You may choose to have it for clarity, but it's not required (and you may choose *not* to have it to avoid redundancy; it's totally a style choice).

(Similarly, you may choose to always have the block — `{...}` — for clarity, but it's not required either.)

Neither of those things matters from a performance standpoint.

There's a third choice to consider:

```
function withElse () {
    var rv;

    if (foo) {
        rv = foo;
    } else if (bar) {
        rv = bar;
    } else {
        rv = baz;
    }

    return rv;
}
```

More verbose, but it has the advantage that the function exits in a single location, which can be useful for debugging. It has the disadvantage, of course, of...being more verbose. :-)

On a simplistic engine, that third choice may have a tiny, tiny performance penalty; on an optimizing engine such as found in modern browsers, I very much doubt it does.

Comment: Or `return foo ? foo : bar ? bar : baz;`, or `return foo || bar || baz;`.

Comment: @torazaburo: LOL yeah, if you want to go the other way on readability/debugging (your first example, not the second). ;-) But I was sort of assuming the conditions and return values weren't actually the same thing...

Comment: @torazaburo don't forget `switch {case foo: return foo; case bar: return bar; case baz: return baz;}`

Comment: @PaulS.: You meant `switch (true) {...`, but yeah, there's that too! :-) (Also `default` rather than `case baz`)

Comment: @PaulS: Love the switch.

Comment: Unfortunately, a truthy value will not match the `true` in `switch (true)`. So needs to be `switch (true) {case !!foo: return foo; case !!bar: return bar; default: return baz; }`

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question, there's no difference between the two programs and you can leave it out if you want.

But, as @torazaburo said "The `else` is going to cost a microsecond or two at compile time". But, for what I know, it doesn't make any difference at run time, so even if you're calling this function 1000x per second you aren't optimizing anything.

```
if (foo) {
    return foo;
} else if (bar) {
    return bar;
} else {
    return baz;
}
```

Will be compiled (by a stupid compiler) to something like this (but in assembly):

```
1. ifnot (foo) goto line 4;
2. return foo;
3. goto line 9;
4. ifnot (foo) goto line 7;
5. return foo;
6. goto line 9;
7. ifnot (foo) goto line 9;
8. return foo;
9.
```

Against:

```
if (foo) return foo;
if (bar) return bar;
return baz;
```

That would be:

```
1. ifnot (foo) goto line 3;
2. return foo;
3. ifnot (foo) goto line 5;
4. return foo;
5. ifnot (foo) goto line 7;
6. return foo;
7.
```

The performance is the same! (I also prefer the second for readability!)

Ps: If you think I'm saying anything wrong, please correct me